# Vim LaTeX-Suite syntax highlighting seems wrong

Tags: vim-latex

The underscores and carrots are highlighted red which is really an eyesore. How can I change/remove this?

[image]

The plugin works fine, so I don't think it's an installation issue.

Update for more details:

Vim 8.1, I doubt I have any conflicting plugins. I have a `tex.vim` file located at `/usr/local/share/vim/vim81/syntax/`.

Comment: Which `vim` version are you using and do you have any other plugins that could come into conflict with the LaTeX plugin?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make vim highlight math properly in the align environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416030/how-do-i-make-vim-highlight-math-properly-in-the-align-environment)

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following line fixed the problem:

```
...
439 call TexNewMathZone("C","equation",1)
440 call TexNewMathZone("D","math",1)
441 call TexNewMathZone("E","align",1) % <---- this is the new line
...
```

No idea why I had to do this. Seems like it should be part of this by default.